# Spash screen stretched not very well in different android screen devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am implementing a splash screen for my app, and use the following code to display image (jpg) for 3 secs when my app is open.The problem is that the image is stretched to the whole screen and other time seems to be compressed depending on screen size. How can i solve this problem? I need the image to fit exactly in each screen size? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:scaleType="fitXY">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="xxxx"/>
```

I use android:scaleType="fitXY" but seems not to work. Image dimensions are 820x615

Answer (score 0):

That doesnt work because every android has a different aspect ratio. The only 2 options are stretch the image using fitxy or you can use CENTER_CROP on the  scaleType and make it expand and chop off the stuff that doesnt fit.

Comment: Thank you. I finally used android:scaleType="fitXY" and image seems better on different devices.